# Interpreting Geojson after pulling with Axios

Tags: reactjs, geojson

Hey I have a React component that is using Axios to grab GeoJSON and then I'm displaying the Json data later.

[here is the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLyTM.png)

and here's the link to the geojson -> http://codeforcary.org/parking/business.geojson

upon trying to access the Data component here 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUd99.png)
I get 'undefined is not an object' on line 5 referring to 'return Data' so im guessing the request to the geojson url is not executing correctly.

I tried changing res.data to JSON.parse(res.data) in Data.js to no avail same error as well as trying to console.log res.data but nothing appears.

I'm guessing this is some sort of formatting error but I can't find in the geojson documentation exactly how u should treat .geojson.

maybe there is some sort of conversion method? thanks.

Comment: Did you try to `console.log` the data before calling `setState` to see if it's correct? If the data is correct can you post the code where you're trying to access the Data component as you mentioned.

Comment: tried that nothing appears on the log. I posted more code above thanks

Comment: You kind of mixing working with data from API and React. As far as I understood you import react component and then try to access some properties of it...
Please try to call `filterLocation` with data from API and not React component